# Error When Posting Back From Drop Down .NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I am new to .NET MVC but have a spent a great deal of time crawling through the other posts on SO for answers to my problem but I haven't been able to find anything.

I am working on extending the Identity 2.0 sample project. I have been able to implement a drop-down using the HTML helper on the Create form for a new ApplicationUser, but I cannot move past an error "*There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'TeamList'*". I can see what the issue is - that the ViewModel and Model for ApplicationUser have a different type for the Team property (ICollection), but I have no idea what to do about it.

My code is below:

Snippet from **ApplicationUser Model**:

```
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Hawks Number")]
    public int number { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Successful Logins")]
    public int successfulLogins { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Password Status")]
    public bool tempPassword { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
```

Snippet from **RegisterViewModel ViewModel**:

```
    [Display(Name = "Assigned Teams")]
    public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
```

Snippet from **UserAdminController Controller**:

```
// GET: /Users/Create
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
    {
        //Get the list of Roles
        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(), "Name", "Name");
        //Get list of Teams
        IdentityDB _db = new IdentityDB();
        ViewBag.Teams = new SelectList(_db.Teams, "Name", "Name");

        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Users/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(RegisterViewModel userViewModel, params string[] selectedRoles)
    {
        IdentityDB _db = new IdentityDB();

        // TODO: RESOLVE ISSUE WITH TEAM SELECTION

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = userViewModel.Email,
                Email = userViewModel.Email,
                firstName = userViewModel.firstName,
                lastName = userViewModel.lastName,
                number = userViewModel.number,
                successfulLogins = 0,
                tempPassword = true,
            };
            var adminresult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, userViewModel.Password);

            //Add User to the selected Roles 
            if (adminresult.Succeeded)
            {
                if (selectedRoles != null)
                {
                    var result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, selectedRoles);
                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(), "Name", "Name");
                        return View();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", adminresult.Errors.First());
                ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Name", "Name");
                return View();

            }
```

Snippet from **View**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Teams, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Teams, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Teams, "- Please Select a Team -", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

It took a while for to move past a "Cannot Implicitly Convert" error to get to this point. I have tried using LINQ to attempt to find the Team record but of course the ViewModel never even picks up the HTTP POST.

Any help would be much appreciated. If there is more information I can provide please just let me know.

Comment: The error means that you trying to bind to `TeamList` (which makes no sense) and that `TeamList` is `null`. you need to show the part of the view where you are generating the dropdownlist (including what model your using in the view)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke - I have edited the question to now include the View information. Please let me know if you need any more information -

Comment: You don't even have a property in your model named `TeamList`. And the POST method you have shown is has a parameter for `RegisterViewModel` which you have not even shown. You need to show the correct code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because in the POST method, your return the view, but have not reassigned a value to `ViewBag.Teams` (as you did in the GET method) so its null. However your dropdownlist is trying to bind to a collection which cannot be done (a `<select>` element only posts back the value of its selected option) and binding will always fail.

Its unclear from your code where you use `Teams` since its not referred to in your POST method, but you need to change your view model to:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
  [Display(Name = "Assigned Teams")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a team")]
  public string SelectedTeam { get; set; }
  public SelectList TeamsList { get; set; }
  ....
}
```

and then in the GET method, initialize your model and return it

```
RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel();
model.TeamsList = new SelectList(_db.Teams, "Name", "Name");
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Teams, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTeam, Model.TeamsList, "- Please Select a Team -", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Teams)
```

and the in the POST method, if you need to return the view because `ModelState` is invalid, then reassign the `SelectList` before returning the view

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(RegisterViewModel model, params string[] selectedRoles)
{
    ....
    // if you need to return the view, then
    model.TeamsList = new SelectList(_db.Teams, "Name", "Name");
    return View(model);
}
```

Side note: Since your using a view model, then it should also include the properties for selecting the roles and delete the `params string[] selectedRoles` parameter from your POST method.

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke - the initialization of the RegisterViewModel triggered it for me, along with where to post the value back to in the RegisterViewModel. Thanks for all your patience!